# Java Socket stuck at new ObjectInputStream()

Tags: java, sockets, serialization

I have this server/client model for a game but it keeps getting stuck at the `ObjectInputStream` initialization.

Here is the code for the client's start method:

```
public void start(){
try {
        Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 24680);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream()); // stuck here
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        startGame();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

here is the server code:

```
try {
    InputStream fis = socket.getInputStream();
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    while (true) {
        ArrayList < Dot > lists = (ArrayList < Dot > ) ois.readObject();
        for (Socket s: sockets) {
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(lists);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does netstat show a connection? Where is the server code that creates the server socket?  There's not enough information here to help.

Comment: can it be a network connectivity issue? try connecting to your server with telnet first.

Comment: You had three goes at this. Only one of them can be correct. You are blocked at `new ObjectInputStream()`, not `getInputStream()` or `new ObjectOutputStream().`

Comment: @JimGarrison If there wasn't a connection there wouldn't be a `Socket` either.

Comment: Provide the complete code where you define the server socket and sockets collection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to construct the `ObjectOutputStream` *before* the `ObjectInputStream` at at least one end, preferably both to avoid accidents. Otherwise `new ObjectInputStream()` blocks trying to read the stream header which hasn't been written yet by the peer's `new ObjectOutputStream()`, because he also is blocked in `new ObjectInputStream().`

Other notes:

- You must use the same object streams for the life of the socket, at both ends, unlike your current code. The reason is the same: the stream header. If you keep creating new `ObjectOutputStreams` you will keep writing new stream headers, which the peer won't expect or understand.
- Remove the `sleep()`. There is no need for sleeps in networking code. They are just literally a waste of time. Cargo-cult programming.